# nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "fastcgi_intercept_errors"

Tags: nginx

Here is my code (starting with line 53):

```
     server  {
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            error_page 404 403 401 500 502 503 504 = http://stackoverflow.com/;
     }
```

Here is the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "fastcgi_intercept_errors" in         /usr/local/nginx//conf/nginx.conf:54
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx//conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

Can anyone help how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check spelling. If you copied it from web, there could be some weird invisible symbols. Retype manually.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I just copy from nginx wiki. It didn't work when I execute ./nginx -t. but I run it in the windows7 nginx is OK. so ...